# What is the duration of the power of the heart shaped herb?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

In **Black Panther** the black panther of Wakanda consumes the heart shaped herb to gain powers. But what is the duration of that power?

If a black panther eats the herb once, will it be effective for his whole life?

Comment: The last part about there being a female black panther sounds like a second question, you should probably ask them separately.

Comment: @Vishwa Please stop tagging questions with the `analysis` tag that aren't analysis questions in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Duration or Time limit is not mentioned.

And it's a high possibility that time period is infinite.

From [MCU wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Heart-Shaped_Herb#cite_note-BP-0),

> Usage of the Heart-Shaped Herbs is seemingly limited to the royal
>   family to allow them to better protect themselves and Wakanda. During
>   the ritual combat in which any tribe or family member may challenge
>   the heir for the throne, the heir must drink a serum to strip away the
>   capabilities of the Heart-Shaped Herbs.

Once ingested, heart-shaped herb enhances it's user's abilities.
from the [same article](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Heart-Shaped_Herb#cite_note-BP-0),

> The heart-shaped herb grants enhanced strength, mobility, stamina,
>   endurance and instincts to those who consume it. There is a
>   preparation able to negate the powers of the herbs, used to allow fair
>   combat trials for the mantles of both Black Panther and King of
>   Wakanda.

Those given powers will remain until it's user drinks another herb, that has the ability to remove the everything that heart-shaped orb provides.

from [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/black-panther-movie-heart-shaped-herb-explained/)

> Black Panther also revealed that ingestion of another herb can
>   actually strip the Black Panther of his powers. This allows T'Challa
>   to compete in ritual combat; the effect was almost instantaneous.
>   T'Challa actually needed to ingest more of the Heart-Shaped Herb in
>   order to recover his abilities.

In MCU, there were no indication that effects from heart-shaped herb will wear off at anytime and there was no indication that Black Panther needed to use heart-shaped orb time to time. only needed to use heart-shaped orb, if there was a challenge and Panther has to drink the other herb to strip off the powers given by hear-shaped orb.

I found another article on [Collider](http://collider.com/black-panther-heart-shaped-herb-explained), which has a detailed explanation about heart-shaped orb on comics.

Answer (score 2):

As in MCU, rather *Black Panther*, the effects are permanent(will remain unless acted upon), effective unless worn out **knowingly**, as in case of using a potion to strip off the herb's effects.